# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in Qt Creator

Tags: python, pandas, qt-creator

I recently created my first qt quick2 pyside application, I had a python class with the name `TestClass` that I had used before in visual studio with no error, I decided to use this class in qt quick pyside application but it has below error:

I had install pyside6, my python version 39.2 and qt version is 5.15.2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\QtProjects\qtforpythonprojects\FirstApplication\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from TestClass import TestClass
  File "D:\QtProjects\qtforpythonprojects\FirstApplication\TestClass.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

When I insert the below command in cmd :

```
>pip3 install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\jooya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in c:\users\jooya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in c:\users\jooya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\jooya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\jooya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: In short `Requirement already satisfied` alongside the `ModuleNotFoundError` means that you install pandas and run a script with different python environments.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I run in qt creator,I think it uses python39

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I run this code(using this class) in visual studio by anaconda env ,How should i crate env in qt creator

Comment: @mohsen Go to Tools-> Options-> Python and check the path of the python it uses, and then run: `/path/of/python -m pip install pandas`

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes,I changed the path of python to anaconda python path.Now it works,Tankyou :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtCreator is probably using a different python than the one you installed pandas. The solution is to use the correct python for this go to Tools-> Options-> Python and select the correct path.